# How do I delete the blue gnome wallpaper from my wallpaper selection in prefs?

Tags: uninstall, desktop-background

I just got rid of adwaita theme in my ubuntu install, but the blue striped wallpaper is still there, how do I find it and remove it manually or run command in terminal to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete the folder /usr/share/themes/Adwaita with either this command in a terminal:

`sudo rm -r /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/`

or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, enter `gksu nautilus /usr/share/themes` and your password when asked, select the folder "Adwaita" and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.